# move folder from root user to my main user in the terminal

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I have a program export a file into a thumb drive. Occasionally, the file get exported into the root user media folder. I need to find a way of moving the file to my main users media folder using terminal commands. How can accomplish this?

Comment: not RPi specific, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50487/how-to-move-all-files-and-folders-via-mv-command

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo mv /path/to/file /path/to/main/user/folder
```